# iOS 7, UIView subviews is nil

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7

Why in iOS 7 [UIView subviews] is always return a nil ?

I am using this [code](http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2013/09/22/ios7-subviews-hierarchy/), but already get a **nil**.

Bug in iOS 7 ?

**EDITED:**

```
TWTweetComposeViewController* tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]  init];
[tweetSheet setInitialText: twitter_descrp];
[tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString: twitter_link]];

NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: twitter_img]];
UIImage* uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[tweetSheet addImage:uiImage];

NSLog(@"subviews: %@", [tweetSheet.view firstSubviewOfClass:[UIButton class]] );
```

Here **firstSubviewOfClass** is got from [iOS7 Subviews Hierarchy](http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2013/09/22/ios7-subviews-hierarchy/)

And inside a NSLog is return this:

```
subviews: (
)
```

Comment: It doesn't. How are you creating your view? Can you show some code.

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question? External links may go down.

Comment: @Fogmeister, question is edited

Comment: How do you know that the `TWTweetComposeViewController` has `UIButtons` on it? Could it be the case that they don't use `UIButton`? All you are showing here is that it doesn't have any buttons. Try `[UIView class]` instead.

Comment: @Amar, question is edited

Comment: @Fogmeister, ok, good idea. After testing i will answer

Comment: It's an exceptionally bad idea to play in the view hierarchy of Apple provided view controllers. They can, and do, change on a release by release basis.

Comment: @Fogmeister, if UIView, still a nil

Comment: @AdamWright is right. You'd be best just not messing with it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AdamWright I'm trying to do this: Find UIButton 'Send' and push him for autosend a Twitter post without UIView

Comment: @Fogmeister For autosend a Twitter post

Comment: Then you should not be using the TWTweetComposer.

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm followed a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531247/send-tweet-via-app-without-the-tweetsheet-in-iphone

Comment: @CReaTuS Then use `TWRequest` and build the request yourself. This is not an appropriate use of `TWTweetComposer`.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 hierarchy changed a lot. As one example, Apple replaced many `UIButton`s by table views and table view cells.

Are you sure there is actually a button in the hierarchy? For debugging, you could try to call

```
NSLog(@"%@", [tweetSheet.view recursiveDescription]); // (ignore the warning)
```

to see how the view hierarchy looks like.

However, in iOS 7 Apple has started to intentionally block access to system views (`UIAlertView` for an example). Sometimes because of security, sometimes because for their own reasons. That means it is possible you won't be able to access the button at all.

You **shouldn't** be accessing the button.

Comment: Thanks, this is true way for Apple. And, how me to realize a AutoPost a twitter post with other way?

Comment: @CReaTuS Doing an automatic post to twitter/fb/etc is explicitely forbidden. That's why Apple is trying to block everyone to access those views.

Comment: recursiveDescription returning a 1 UIVIew, it seems, this is a Tweet UIView